# Can we get back path from signatures?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

This question is related to rough path theory. A link to wikipedia is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rough_path
It appears path and signatures has one to one mapping (like Fourier transform), the question is, given a signature can we get back the path from which it is derived? It is assumed hat the initial condition is zero or known and there is no retraces or double back on itself in the entire path (never crosses itself). Any comments would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an explicit reconstruction? I think that's still an open question. I know that T. Lyons did some stuff on sound compression and noted that it was rather difficult to get back the path of the signature.

Comment: And I'm pretty sure not having loops is not sufficient for being unique. If there is a a variable in the path that is strictly decreasing (i.e. time), then there is a bijective relation between the signature and the path, otherwise the path is unique up to a tree like structure. Most texts on rough path theory should cover this.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Thank you for your comments, do you have reference for your comments: " If there is a a variable in the path that is strictly decreasing (i.e. time), then there is a bijective relation between the signature and the path". I want to know if one can introduce a variable of that form artificially to be useful.

Comment: I meant strictly increasing of course, so you can always add the time variable to make the path unique, as stated in: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.03788.pdf on page 18 and the references mentioned on that page. It looks like I remembered it wrong, so it's better if you investigate yourself! The linked paper is quite basic on the mathematical theory, but in general is very nice as a high-level explanation. And it has solid references.